# Retrieve Dictionary from dictionary in C#.net

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this

```
{
  "A" : {
    "A1" : {
      "er" : false,
       "hy" : false,
       "fv" : false,
       "fr" : false
          },
     "A2" : {
       "fr" : false,
       "ty" : false,
       "ty" : false,
          },
   "B" : {
     "B1" : {
       "er" : false,
       "hy" : false,
       "fv" : false,
       "fr" : false
         },
     "B2" : {
      "fr" : false,
      "ty" : false,
      "ty" : false,
   },
  }
}
```

I am trying to retrieve values of A1 and A2 dictionary as a separate dictionaries

I have tried

```
 Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> dict =
 jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>>json.ToString());

       Dictionary<string, object> dict1 = dict["A"];

 Dictionary<string, object> dict2 = dict1["A1"];//error here
```

Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

how to resolve this?

Comment: Instead of posting the pseudo code it would have been more helpful to see the initialization of the real dictionary.

Comment: what is that extra bracket after `ToString` closing?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve it:

`Dictionary<string, object> dict2 = (Dictionary<string, object>) dict1["A1"];`